# Format file to have 5 numbers per line

Tags: c, text-files

I am working on a text file containing integers separated by spaces, for instance:

```
1 2 57 99 8 14 22 36 98 445 1001 221 332 225 789 1111115 147 0 1 21321564 544 489 654 61266 5456 15 19
```

I would like to re-format this file to only contain 5 integers in any line but the last, and at most 5 integers in the last line.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

FILE *f; // main file (A.txt)
FILE *g; // file copy (B.txt)

// open A.txt to read data
f = fopen("file/path/here/A.txt", "r");
if (f == NULL) {
    printf("Read error.\n");
    fclose(f);
    return -1;
}

// open B.txt to write data
g = fopen("file/path/here/B.txt", "w");
if (g == NULL) {
    printf("Write error.\n");
    fclose(g);
    return -2;
}

int line = 1; // first line in output file
while (!feof(f)) { // not end-of-file
    char number[1000];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        if (fscanf(f, "%s", number) == 1) { // one number read
            fprintf(g, "%s", line + i, number);
        }
    line += i;
}

// close files
fclose(f);
fclose(g);

return 0;
}
```

When I run this in Code::Blocks, I get the 'Segmentation fault (core dumped) Process returned 139' message. I suspect that the problem lies in the 'if' statement and my use of formats. Needless to say, I'm relatively new to C. How might I fix this?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/3049655). And don't `fclose(f)` if `f` is `NULL`.

Comment: Use your debugger which will kindly tell you where exactly the segfault happens.

Comment: `fprintf(g, "%s", line + i, number);` --> `fprintf(g, "%s ",  number);`, `line += i;` --> `line += 1; fprintf(g, "\n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple reason for your segmentation fault is expression `fprintf(g, "%s", line + i, number);`, in which you state to pass a pointer to a string (i.e. `char*`), but actually pass a number (i.e. `line + i`); hence, the value of `line + i`, which is probably `1`, ..., is interpreted as a pointer to memory address `1`, which is not allowed to be addressed. It is as if you wrote `fprintf(g, "%s", 1)`, which crashes, too;

So basically change this expression into `fprintf(g, "%s", number);`, and it should at least not crash (unless you have numbers with more than 999 digits).

There are some other issues in your code, e.g. that you open `B.txt` for write and assign it to `g`, but then you test and close the file using variable `f`.
But maybe above "crash solution" brings you forward, such that you can work further on your own. Note that - if `B.txt` failed opening, then your code would also have crashed because of passing `NULL` as file stream argument to `fprintf`.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with the use of `fscanf` and then `fprintf`.

`fscanf` knows how to parse a string into a number. E.g. `fscanf(f, "%d", &var);`. This reads a signed integer from the file handle `f` into the variable `var`. This can then be printed with `fprintf`.

As it stands, the first `fscanf` slurps the entire input into `number` (assuming that 1000 `char` is enough) and the following ones are not expected to be called